# dSYM not uploaded by CLI command

Tags: ios, upload, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

I'm trying to upload dSYM file of my app reading it from the .xcarchive bundle by the Fabric CLI command:

```
upload-symbols -p ios -gsp GoogleService-Info.plist <path to xcarchive/dSYMs>
```

But unfortunately I always get this error:

> Error Domain=com.crashlytics.mac.error-domain.process-dsym Code=4 "This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This version of OSX is not able to perform the necessary dSYM transformations.}

BitCode is not activated in my Build Settings

upload-symbols version is: 1.5.0 build 11.
MacBook Pro 2019 with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 - 32 GB.

Is anybody experiencing the same issue?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Is this is a Firebase app or have you migrated your app over from Fabric? If this is a migrated app, then passing `-a <api_key>` instead of `-gsp <path_to_GoogleService-info.plist>` to upload-symbols will resolve the issue.

Comment: It's a Firebase app, not migrated from Fabric. Xcode version is: 10.3 (10G8)

Comment: Can you reach out support(at)fabric(dot)io?

Comment: having the same thing after updating to macOS Catalina. with Xcode 11.1
didn't work `-a <api_key>`
I have below script on build phase
`"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${SRCROOT}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to Firebase.

Comment: They answered me to update Fabric and Crashlytics pods to the latest release, but the issue was still present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue using fastlane:

```
zip -r dSYM.zip MyApp.xcarchive/dSYMs/

fastlane run upload_symbols_to_crashlytics dsym_path:"dSYM.zip" gsp_path:"<path_to_GoogleService-info.plist>" binary_path:"Pods/Fabric"
```